# (Executing a built in program in UNIX (C)

Tags: c, linux, unix, operating-system, exec

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    #include<unistd.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    int main(int argc,char *argv[],char *envp[])
    {
        int pid;
        int id;
        pid=fork();
        if(pid<0)
        {
            printf("\n Error ");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if(pid==0)                         //Child process
        {
        execve("a",argv,envp);  //Problem is in here
            printf("\n Pid of child process is %d ",getpid());  //Finds the id of the child process
        exit(0);
        }
        else                                //Parent process
        {
    wait(3);
    printf("\n Pid of parent process is %d ",getpid());
            exit(1);
        }

    }
```

I am trying to execute a program named a in UNIX but it does not work probably because I use the wrong exec command or the program a is in a different directory but I am not sure.When I execute this from terminal it gives me the id of child and parent process but does not notify me about the program a.

Comment: Have you read the manpage for *any* of the functions you call?

Comment: What will happen if you run this code, will returns error or just not perform the expected results?

Comment: If the printf call is executing, something is FUed. Have you checked the value of errno? Done a strerror call?

Comment: It gives me the id of child process call and parent process call.I am aware that my program does not return an integer in its current state but maybe it is not needed in the newest version of Ubuntu.It does not make any sense but I could not find a better explanation.Exit statements might be the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me.  I had to change the call to wait to:

```
int retStat;
wait(&retStat);
```

because wait really wants to return a value and the program crashed without it.  Did you check that your a program is in your path or are you including the path in the exec call?

Comment: Turns out it was because of the directory was different.Seems like in the newer versions of Ubuntu you dont need to return an integer value when you have an exit statement